# JPA and ORACLE function: error when call a stored procedure using NamedNativeQuery

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, jpa, stored-procedures

I have an Oracle function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SOL.UPDATE_LD_OAUDITORID (
vCUSTOMERID       NUMBER,
vAPPOINTOFCAID    NUMBER,
vAUDITORID        NUMBER,
vOAUDITORID       NUMBER)

RETURN NUMBER
IS
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;

vGROUPID      NUMBER;
rTN           NUMBER;

CURSOR c
IS
  SELECT COMPANYID,
         GROUPID,
         PERIODID,
         PROCESSID,
         CUSTOMERID,
         APPOINTOFCAID,
         AUDITORID
    FROM LIQUIDATIONSDETAILS
   WHERE     CUSTOMERID = vCUSTOMERID
         AND APPOINTOFCAID = vAPPOINTOFCAID
         AND AUDITORID = vAUDITORID
         AND (       PERIODID = fn_periodcurrent
                 AND PROCESSID = FN_PROCESSCURRENT
              OR PERIODID = fn_periodNEXT AND PROCESSID = FN_PROCESSNEXT) FOR UPDATE;

TYPE nt_type IS TABLE OF c%ROWTYPE;
l_arr         nt_type;
DML_ERRORS    EXCEPTION;
PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (DML_ERRORS, -24381);
l_errors      NUMBER;
errorCnt      NUMBER;
errString     VARCHAR2 (4000);
l_idx         NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT FN_CURRENTGROUP (vOAUDITORID) INTO vGROUPID FROM DUAL;

OPEN c;

LOOP
  FETCH c
  BULK COLLECT INTO l_arr
  LIMIT 500;

  EXIT WHEN l_arr.COUNT = 0;

  BEGIN
     FORALL i IN 1 .. l_arr.COUNT SAVE EXCEPTIONS
        UPDATE liquidationsdetails
           SET groupid = vgroupid, auditorid = vOAUDITORID
         WHERE     COMPANYID = l_arr (i).COMPANYID
               AND GROUPID = l_arr (i).GROUPID
               AND PERIODID = l_arr (i).PERIODID
               AND PROCESSID = l_arr (i).PROCESSID
               AND CUSTOMERID = l_arr (i).CUSTOMERID
               AND APPOINTOFCAID = l_arr (i).APPOINTOFCAID
               AND AUDITORID = l_arr (i).AUDITORID;

     RTN := 1;
  EXCEPTION
     WHEN dml_errors
     THEN                        -- Now we figure out what failed and why.
        errorCnt := SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.COUNT;
        errString :=
           'Number of statements that failed: ' || TO_CHAR (errorCnt);

        RTN := 0;
  END;
END LOOP;

CLOSE C;

COMMIT;

RETURN RTN;
END;
/
```

A dummy entity bean with namednativequery the call of the function

```
@Entity
@NamedNativeQueries({
@javax.persistence.NamedNativeQuery(name = "updateldoauditorid", query = ""
        + "{? =  call UPDATE_LD_OAUDITORID(:customerid, :appointofcaid, :auditorid, :oauditorid)}", resultClass = DummyEntity.class,
        hints = {
            @javax.persistence.QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.callable", value = "true")})})

public class DummyEntity implements Serializable {
...
```

a stateless session

```
@Override
public int spUpdate_ld_oauditorid(String customerid, String appointofcaid, String auditorid, String oauditorid) {
    Integer isup = (Integer) em.createNamedQuery("updateldoauditorid")
            .setParameter(customerid, customerid)
            .setParameter(appointofcaid, appointofcaid)
            .setParameter(auditorid, auditorid)
            .setParameter(oauditorid, oauditorid)
            .getSingleResult();

    return isup;
}
```

a jsp page that call the following

```
try {
        update = dummyFacade.spUpdate_ld_oauditorid(customerid, appointofcaid, auditorid, oauditorid);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am getting the error

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.apache.jsp.members.appointsofcas.liquidations.liquidations_005fa_005foauditorid_jsp.Updateldoauditorid(liquidations_005fa_005foauditorid_jsp.java:96)     at
>   org.apache.jsp.members.appointsofcas.liquidations.liquidations_005fa_005foauditorid_jsp._jspService(liquidations_005fa_005foauditorid_jsp.java:415)
>   when execute the jsp page

Comment: Probably not your issue.  But a function that does DML is a bad idea-- you'd want to use a procedure for that.  And using an autonomous transaction for anything other than writing a persistent log is a bug waiting to happen.

Comment: Justin Cave What you recomend for that?

Comment: Change it to a stored procedure.  Get rid of the autonomous transaction.  I would get rid of the commit as well-- let the application handle transaction management.  Your error management also looks incredibly suspect-- do you really only want to return a string that tells you how many failures you had in the last batch of up to 500 rows?  With no indication of which rows failed or that thousands of other errors may have been encountered?  Or what the errors were?

Comment: Justin Cave is possible to give me an example? For example What can I do with procedure (Function)? Drop it? My error managment was copy from an example. This function update max 2 records. I need only to return to the application if an exception come..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your stateless session bean, you are setting the parameters incorrectly. You are using the value of the parameter twice, you probably forgot the `""` for the first parameter when you called to `setParameter()`.

```
@Override
public int spUpdate_ld_oauditorid(String customerid, String appointofcaid, String auditorid, String oauditorid) {
    Integer isup = (Integer) em.createNamedQuery("updateldoauditorid")
        .setParameter("customerid", customerid)
        .setParameter("appointofcaid", appointofcaid)
        .setParameter("auditorid", auditorid)
        .setParameter("oauditorid", oauditorid)
        .getSingleResult();

return isup;
}
```

Comment: Ok David I change the code and I take an other error
A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB DummyFacade
...
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy283.spUpdate_ld_oauditorid(Unknown Source)

Comment: Setting the parameters for the query was one of the problems in your code. It is hard to say what is your problem now without a full stack trace of the error.

Comment: how to add the full StackTrace?

Comment: A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB DummyFacade, method: public int sol.session.DummyFacade.spUpdate_ld_oauditorid(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)|#]

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: NamedQuery of name: updateldoauditorid not found.

Comment: Ok I must to specify the classes Dummy Entity in the persistence.xml

Comment: Now I take the following error
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 2
Error Code: 17041

Comment: Ok I change it the NamedQuery but I take a new error is crazy:

Comment: Call: {? =  call UPDATE_LD_OAUDITORID(?, ?, ?, ?)}
 bind => [5 parameters bound]
Query: ReadAllQuery(name="updateldoauditorid" referenceClass=DummyEntity sql="{? =  call UPDATE_LD_OAUDITORID(?, ?, ?, ?)}")